# .NET MVC Custom validation (without data annotation)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

use .NET MVC and code-first EF to implement of requested functionality. Business objects are relatively complex and I use `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.IValidatableObject` to validate business object.
Now I'm trying to find the way, how to show validation result from business object, using MVC ValidationSummary without using data annotations. For example (very simplified):

Business Object:

```
    public class MyBusinessObject : BaseEntity, IValidatableObject
    {
        public virtual IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
           return Validate();
        }
        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate()
        {
           List<ValidationResult> results = new List<ValidationResult>();

           if (DealType == DealTypes.NotSet)
           {
                results.Add(new ValidationResult("BO.DealType.NotSet", new[] { "DealType" }));
           }

           return results.Count > 0 ? results.AsEnumerable() : null;
        }
    }
```

Now in my MVC controller I have something like this:

```
    public class MyController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult New(MyModel myModel)
        {
           MyBusinessObject bo = GetBoFromModel(myModel);
           IEnumerable<ValidationResult> result = bo.Validate();
           if(result == null)
           {
               //Save bo, using my services layer
               //return RedirectResult to success page
           }

           return View(myModel);
        }
    }
```

In view, I have `Html.ValidationSummary();`.
**How I can pass `IEnumerable<ValidationResult>` to the ValidationSummary?**

I tried to find an answer by googling, but all examples I found describes how to show validation summary using data annotations in Model and not in Business object.

Thanks

Comment: MyBusinessObject can't be a model, since it much more complex then the Model and it performs much more validations. I don't want to throw exception from EF and then redirect to error page, I just want to show in view, what fields where invalid in BusinessObject.

Comment: Clarify - the implementation of IValidatableObject must be in viewmodel namely in MyModel-class. You gave the viewmodel's concern (user input validation) to business entity - it isnt correct.

Comment: @vladimir77 According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193959.aspx, I didn't found anything incorrect by using IValidatableObject with code-first.

Comment: Then following this article you should use MyBusinessObject in New-action not MyModel, isn't it? Why do you use MyModel? I suppose you dont understand the purposes of viewmodel (flatten object) :( it's really important for working with MVC.

Comment: Please see ['MVC pluralsight tutorial - Working with Data: Validation and Mapping'](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/models-(data))

Comment: @vladimir77 thanks for good link for learning more on subject, but I still think that using IValidatableObject with Model not denies the use of it with EF. Code-first supports data annotations as well as view model. So for me (and for Julie Lerman from link I gave you), it's absolutely fine to use IValidatableObject for entity objects if needed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add property, say BusinessError, in the model

in the View do the following

```
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BusinessError)
```

Then in your controller whenever you have error do the following

```
ModelState.AddModelError("BussinessError", your error)
```

Comment: But in this way I should iterate through the IEnumerable by writing "foreach" or something?

Comment: In a sea of confusion and smelly code, this is the lighthouse. Alex, you should be following this example; it is the most graceful way to add errors to Modelstate for display into the ValidationSummary.

Comment: @Moby'sStuntDouble, thanks for the point...I missed ModelState in an answer, i need to investigate it, it looks like this is what I need :)

Answer (score 4):

I would have a look at [FluentValidation](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation). It's a framework for validation without data annoations. I've used it with great success in some projects for complex validation, and it is also usable outside of the MVC-project.

Here is the sample code from their page:

```
using FluentValidation;

public class CustomerValidator: AbstractValidator<Customer> {
  public CustomerValidator() {
    RuleFor(customer => customer.Surname).NotEmpty();
    RuleFor(customer => customer.Forename).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Please specify a first name");
    RuleFor(customer => customer.Company).NotNull();
    RuleFor(customer => customer.Discount).NotEqual(0).When(customer => customer.HasDiscount);
    RuleFor(customer => customer.Address).Length(20, 250);
    RuleFor(customer => customer.Postcode).Must(BeAValidPostcode).WithMessage("Please specify a valid postcode");
  }

  private bool BeAValidPostcode(string postcode) {
    // custom postcode validating logic goes here
  }
}

Customer customer = new Customer();
CustomerValidator validator = new CustomerValidator();
ValidationResult results = validator.Validate(customer);

bool validationSucceeded = results.IsValid;
IList<ValidationFailure> failures = results.Errors;
```

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework should throw a `DbEntityValidationException` if there are validation errors. You can then use the exception to add the errors to the `ModelState`.

```
try
{
     SaveChanges();
}
catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
{
     AddDbErrorsToModelState(ex);
}
return View(myModel);

protected void AddDbErrorsToModelState(DbEntityValidationException ex)
{
     foreach (var validationErrors in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
     {
          foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
          {
               ModelState.AddModelError(validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to pass the contents of IEnumerate and keep taking advantage of Html.ValidationSummary is by updating ModelState.

You can find a good discussion on how to update the ModelState [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719390/updating-modelstate-with-model-object).